# Compile error .c file into .dll

Tags: c#, dll

**What I need to do:**

**1**. Create an application in that allows a user to define a function

Now, I need to compile it to .dll . After compilation, the .dll should be loaded into another C# application which will call that function.

Comment: Why load a `C` function in a `C#` Application?

Comment: If tcc is what I think it is (turbo c), you can't use `__declspec(dllexport)` which is a visual c syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't need to compile C to use pointers; C# has those too... and the odds are, if you can compile and load an unsafe DLL file, you can use the `unsafe` keyword to leverage them. Your solution will likely be much cleaner if you stick to using one language.

As for the error message, it's not clear whether you're using Turbo C++ (which is no more a C compiler than a rock is a hammer) or Tiny C, but either way `__declspec(dllexport)` is a Microsoft extension. Perhaps you could try using Microsofts compiler (which isn't a very nice compiler, either), if you wish to use a Microsoft extension... Particularly if you're going to attempt to use such a DLL from another Microsoft product; They're going to expect a compatible ABI!